# How to mount hard drive (physical disk) which is a part of LVM in Ubuntu Server 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, mount, lvm2

Newly installed Ubuntu 22.04 to a server.

The logical volume is already mounted (by default) to / during installation of 22.04 to a Dell server.

When I try to mount the "mapper" (to anywhere such as `/media/hd01`), this mapper gets installed twice. (therefore I removed this mounting, now only installed to / as in the beginning).

I just want to mount my physical drive (sda3) so that I can use it in a directory such as /media/hd01.

I tried to mount with:

`sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/drive`  leading to the error
`mount: /media/hd01: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.`

Trying to add file type using `mkfs.ext4` gives the error `/dev/sda3 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here`

Giving up with the sda3, I tried to extend the LV then, but somehow usable space became 0.
VG and LV are active.

How shall I mount & be able to use my physical hard drive?

outputs added

```
b@b1001:/$ vgs

VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr    VSize VFree
ubuntu-vg 1    1   0  uz--n- <1.09t <1014.20g

b@b1001:/$ lvs
LV        VG   Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Meta% Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg  -wi-ao----  100.00g

b@b1001:/$ df -h
Filesystem                        Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
tmpfs                             26G  1.9M 26G   1%   /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--1v 98G  11G  82G   12%  /
tmpfs                             126G 0    126G  0%   /dev/shm
tmpfs                             5.0M 0    5.0M  0%   /run/lock
/dev/sda2                         2.0G 131M 1.7G  8%   /boot
/dev/sda1                         1.1G 6.1M 1.1G  1%   /boot/efi
tmpfs                             26G  4.0K 26G   1%   /run/user/1000

b@b1001:/$ lsblk

NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                     7:0     0 63.4M  1 loop   /snap/core20/1974
loop1                     7:1     0 111.9M 1 loop   /snap/lxd/24322
loop2                     7:2     0 53.3M  1 loop   /snap/snapd/19457
sda                       8:0     0 1.1T   0 disk
__sda1                    8:1     0 1G     0 part   /boot/efi 
__sda2                    8:2     0 2G     0 part   /boot
__sda3                    8:3     0 1.1T   0 part   
____ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0   0 100G   0 lvm    /

b@b1001:/$ pvs
PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree    
/dev/sda3 ubuntu-vg  lvm2 a--  <1.09t <1014.20g
```

Comment: What you are asking is unclear, and you have not provided sufficient details.   If this question is the same as the previous one, the solution is to gain rep on this site and then place a bounty on that question, not open a new none.

Comment: If this question is different to the previous one, please paste the full output of "vgs", "lvs"  and  "df" commands.    What do you understand about the relationships between physical volumes, volume groups and logical volumes?

Comment: It may be that your LVM setup has not been initialised.   This is something the OS normally does automatically, but you can often do it manually with commands "vgscan -ay" followed by "lvscan -ay" which should create /dev/vgname/lvname devices you can mount.

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new in servers, in ubuntu, and in this website. I just want to be able to mount my physical drive (sda3) so that I can use it in a directory such as /mnt/hd1.

Comment: Please add the output of "pvs" - I expect that it will show that /dev/sda3 is used by your VG - but there is something that does not fully add up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use /dev/sda3 directly for storage I think you will have to rebuild the box, as /dev/sda3 is used by LVM and part of it is mounted as the root partition.

The good thing though is that LVM is an intermediate layer between the disk and the OS, so what you can do is carve off the unused space and make a block device you can mount on /media.    According to your output you have quite a lot of space you can use for this purpose - somewhere between 850 and 1015 gigs free.

In order to create a new partition for /media using some of the space in LVM, use the following command :

```
  lvcreate -n media ubuntu-vg -L XXXg
```

where XXX is the size you wish to allocate in gigs

or

```
  lvcreate -n media ubuntu-vg -l XXX
```

where XXX is the number of extents (blocks) you wish to allocate.  This is more precise then using gigs.  You can see the number of extents you have available by typing "lvdisplay" and looking at the "Free  PE / Size" line.

Once you have created the new LVM device you can then treat it like a block device - ie you can format it using

```
   mkfs.ext4 /dev/ubuntu-vg/media
```

and you can then mount it with a command like

```
   mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/media /media
```

and/or add a line in your fstab file to automatically mount it.

Pro tip - consider leaving some free space in the LVM setup - that will enable you to take snapshots of the device which may come in useful later.   (Its not a requirement of LVM, just something that can be useful)